# PIP Activity causing application not Responsive Android Q

Tags: android, xamarin

I am implementing pip mode in my app where I open the PIP actvity from navigation menu item. pip mode works fine but when I click back any other item in the menu logcat shows message **handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@8ef8d1f**

Below is the link i have referred.

[Link](https://www.zoftino.com/android-picture-in-picture-mode-example)

**BaseActivityHelper.cs**

```
relativeImageGallery.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var pip_activity = new Intent(_activity, typeof(PictureinPictureActivity));
                pip_activity.PutExtra("videoUrl", "http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8"/*"rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"*/);
                _activity.StartActivity(pip_activity);


            };
```

**PictureinPictureActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PictureinPictureMode);

        tb = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        vv = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView);
        SetSupportActionBar(tb);
        setVideoView(Intent);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        // Create your application here
        pip = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.pip);
        progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.indeterminateBar);
        vv.SetMediaController(mediaController);
        vv.SetOnPreparedListener(this);
        vv.SetOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this, pictureInPictureParamsBuilder, vv));
        pip.SetTypeface(FontFactory.GetFontAwesome(this), TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        pip.Text = "\uf063";

    }
```

**Base Activity**

```
 public class BaseActivity:SlidingFragmentActivity
{
    public static bool IsBackButtonPressedOnce = false;
    const int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    const int StORAGE_REQUEST = 2;
    const int CHECK_IN_REQUEST = 3;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetBehindContentView(Resource.Layout.menu_frame);
        /* 
         * Support of scaling for lower end devices
         * This method is called only if the device Api Should be less than Nougat and the font scale should be greater than 1.5 
         * 
         * */
        SetTabletFontScaling();
        Util.StatusBarColor(this);

        BaseActivityHelper baseActivityHelper = new BaseActivityHelper(this, SlidingMenu);
        baseActivityHelper.OnCreateHelper();
    }
```

**Note:** This issue occures only in Android Q

Comment: I write a demo base on the link above,it works on Android Q emulator,i didn't produce your issue,could you show your complete main activity codes or share a test project.

Comment: As in Demo there are no more activities. In my project i have navigation drawer and on on click of each item different activities are opened. The problem surely exists

Comment: what's the `_activity` ,did you finish it  somewhere ?

Comment: This is baseactivity instance that we pass in constructor. I have updated the code for more clearity. And yes we finish this activity but on a particular clickevent that i have not triggered. In BaseActivity this pass in constructor is _activity

Comment: Do you have any activities extends the BaseActivity ? and in which activity you would open the PictureinPictureActivity ?

Comment: I open the Picture in Picure activity in BaseActivtyHelper i.e SlidingMenu.And yes I have Many Activities that extends BaseActivties. basically all the NavigationBar Items extends BaseActivity

Comment: could you share a simple sample ? then i could test quickly.

Comment: I will try to give you a sample ASAP

Comment: You can clone this project. https://github.com/benbaxter/pip-navigation. Problem occures in this also

Comment: I finally found the solution of this problem. By targeting the app to Android Q it will solve the problem.. Thanks @LeoZhu-MSFT